# SQL query in one command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

Two Tables:
 first Table name: `employee_1`          |        Second table name:employee_2

```
code | Name | Salary | Month|Year    code | Name | Salary |Post |Month |Year
-----+------+--------+------+--      -----+------+--------+-----+------+----
1    | A    |   1000 | May  | 2017    1   | A    | 2000   |clerk|April |2017
2    | B    |   1150 | May  | 2017    2   | B    | 3000   |clerk|April |2017
1    | A    |   1200 | June | 2017
2    | B    |   1150 | June | 2017
1    | A    |   4000 | July | 2017
2    | B    |   3500 | July | 2017
```

Output should be like this for year=2017:

```
code  | Name |April | May  | June  | July
------+------+------+-------+------+-
 1    | A    |2000  | 1000 | 1200  | 4000
 2    | B    |3000  | 1150 | 1150  | 3500
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Google "SQL pivot query."  By the way, in the real world you would almost certainly have a year component in addition to the month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether you can write an SQL query in one command for the output because here you want the row (Month) to be changed into the column. So the ideal solution will be writing a pivot query.

you can use the PIVOT function to transform the data from rows into columns.

It sounds like you will need to use dynamic SQL if the Months are unknown or if they dynamically changed.

```
create table employee (code int , name varchar(100), salary money, Month1 varchar(100));


INSERT INTO employee (code, name, salary, Month1)
VALUES
(1   ,   'A'   ,    1000   ,   'may'),
(2   ,   'B'   ,    1150   ,   'may'),
(1   ,   'A'   ,    1200   ,   'June'),
(2   ,   'B'   ,    1150   ,   'June'),
(1    ,  'A'    ,   4000  ,    'July'),
(2    ,  'B'     ,  3500  ,    'July')

DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Month1) 
                    from employee
                    group by Month1
                    order by Month1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

        select @cols

set @query = 'SELECT code,name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select code, name, salary,Month1
                from employee
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(salary)
                for month1 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute (@query)
```

**#With Year as requested in comment**

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @year As varchar(100)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Month1) 
                    from employee1
                    group by Month1
                    order by Month1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @year = '2018'

set @query = 'SELECT code,name,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select code, name, salary,Month1,year
                from employee1
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(salary)
                for month1 in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p  where year ='+ @year +''

execute (@query)
```

## with respect to two tables

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @year As varchar(100),
    @cols1 as varchar(1000),
    @cols2 as varchar(1000)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Month1) 
                    from employee1
                    group by Month1
                    order by Month1
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @cols1 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Month) 
                    from employee2
                    group by Month
                    order by Month
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @cols2 = @cols1 +',' + @cols


set @year = '2017'

set @query = 'SELECT code,name,' + @cols2 + ' from 
             (
                select code, name, salary,Month1,year
                from employee1 
                union all
                select code,name,salary,Month,year from employee2
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(salary)
                for month1 in (' + @cols2 + ')
            ) p  where year ='+ @year +''

execute (@query)
```

Comment: are u going to add a new column called year or concatenate the existing month with a year like 'May 2017'

Comment: why there is another table ABC with an extra column compared to PQR. Whether that table should be joined with pqr for your result. I have written a dynamic SQL so if there is a data in your table for April then I assume that a new column called 'April' will be pivoted and it will show in the output. Do you face any issue in that case on trying.

Comment: Man! you are just great, Thank you soooooo much!!!!!!!!!